# How to do whitelist of IP's in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to block every IP address from accessing my site except one or two IP's provided by myself. I have tried many modules but nothing seems to work.

```
var express = require('express')
var AccessControl = require('express-ip-access-control');
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var middleware = AccessControl(options);
 app.use(AccessControl(options));

var options = {
    mode: 'deny',
    denys: [],
    allows: ['**8.1**.1.**'],
    forceConnectionAddress: false,
    log: function(clientIp, access) {
        console.log(clientIp + (access ? ' accessed.' : ' denied.'));
    },

    statusCode: 401,
    redirectTo: '',
    message: 'Unauthorized'
};

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log(' app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

on running and accessing my site from my above code i am getting the console message as

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 accessed.
::ffff:127.0.0.1 accessed.
::ffff:127.0.0.1 accessed.
::ffff:127.0.0.1 accessed.
```

any help?

Comment: i didnt understand your code, make it clearly

Comment: [Read the fine manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ip-access-control#allow-mode-whilelist): to implement a whitelist the mode should be _"allow"_.

Comment: I haven't seen you put any ip in your `allows`

Comment: sry i have changed it now...yet same results

Comment: i have also changed my mode and executed but i am getting the same results @robertklep.

Comment: @Jagadeesh `mode : 'allow', allows : [ ... ]`

Comment: you must defined your `options` first before using it.

Comment: ya i did it still no response i am getting accessed to my site .. i am a denyed userip.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add your own middleware that checks the IPs, no need to include another module.

You can see the ip from the request with `req.connection.remoteAddress`.

Before you define your routes, add something like this:

```
// Custom Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
let validIps = ['::12', '127.0.0.1']; // Put your IP whitelist in this array

  if(validIps.includes(req.connection.remoteAddress)){
      // IP is ok, so go on
      console.log("IP ok");
      next();
  }
  else{
      // Invalid ip
      console.log("Bad IP: " + req.connection.remoteAddress);
      const err = new Error("Bad IP: " + req.connection.remoteAddress);
      next(err);
  }
})
```

This will throw an error if an invalid ip comes in. Below all your routes, add something like this:

```
// Error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Error handler', err);
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send("Something broke");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your `options` *before* you use them. Otherwise, you're passing in `undefined` to `app.use(AccessControl(options))`.

Not sure how this is compiling for you, but adding the following line to the top of your script might help show a few more errors that would help.

```
'use strict';
```

---

Secondly, according to the [express-ip-access-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ip-access-control) documentation:

> `'allow'` mode (Whilelist):
>
> Deny by default, only allow IPs in the whitelist (`allows`) and not excluded by the blacklist (`denys`).

So change `options.mode` from `'deny'` to `'allow'`.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Please elaborate.

Comment: var options = {
    mode: 'allow',
    denys: [],
    allows: ['**8.1**.1.**'],
    forceConnectionAddress: false,
    log: function(clientIp, access) {
        console.log(clientIp + (access ? ' accessed.' : ' denied.'));
    },

    statusCode: 401,
    redirectTo: '',
    message: 'Unauthorized'
};
var middleware = AccessControl(options);
 app.use(AccessControl(options));
still whitelisting not done..

Comment: You need to show what the output was. I can't help you with piecemeal information. From the looks of it, I would suggest reviewing the IP wildcard patterns. The documentation indicates it only supports CIDR, so `8.1.1.*` would really be `8.1.1.0/24`. _Please_ read documentation and research before asking questions on SO.